# How do they go down a level when already inside a dream?

Tags: inception

I see how you would go from reality to a dream  using a real PASIV device. But how do they hook themselves up to one in a dream when going down several levels? Where does the device come from and how do they use it when they are all *physically* asleep and dreaming? Is the level of sedation managed between dream levels somehow? Is a level just an abstraction for a more heavily sedated state controlled by someone in reality?

Comment: It feels like you've already answered your own question. One of the dreamers dreams up a PASIV machine, they hook the subject up to it and away they go. No additional explanation is offered, any more than they explain how Ariadne designs the mazes.